# Multiboot (Windows) with partitions non accessible from one to the other

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot

Computers are never enough for me.....unfortunately.
So i had an idea now of upgrading my computer, upgrade it to full specs (as usual), and create a multi-boot drive.
Possibly, about 6 or 7 boot partitions. All will be on Windows 10 Professional, and possibly a single Windows 7 Professional, or maybe none at all. (we will see)

Now, the first question is, can i multi-boot the drive but somehow contain each partition in a way that each partition cant see the others on device manager or in the "my computer" screen and also will not interfere with each each other?

There will not be any funny business (fear of viruses) on any of the partitions, i just want to keep things clean, tidy, simple, straight forward and isolated for stability reasons and the usual case of human behavior being lazy, saving random files to random drives. (done that, been there)

Having mulitpple SSDs and swapping them each time is not an option, as most laptops nowadays require you to not only remove a bunch of screws, but also need to pry open the bottom shells to access the drive etc.
CD/DVD storage caddies are also not an option as the computer i plan on purchasing does not have a CD/DVD bay.
Plus in both cases the hassle and clutter would be overwhelming.

I'd prefer to use a boot menu and just select the partition i need, then just shut down and boot to another partition. (if seamless switching from one boot option to the other without rebooting, was a thing, sure i would do that)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would encrypting each with bitlocker do?  The separate instances would be able to see there were other partitions but not read/update the data (except to reformat).  It is included in 10 Pro but you'd need 7 Ultimate not Professional.  Otherwise using separate VMs or native booting separate vhdx may be worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough to have multiple boot partition on a UEFI computer.
In case of a problem you might need to increase the size of the UEFI partition.

You may use Device Manager on each instance to delete the drive-letters of all
other partitions except its own `C:`. This way, no interference is possible.

Comment: But have you considered virtual machines instead of partitioning your disk to small pieces?